# Angular 2 Firebase passwordless login - register another person

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

so I searched for a while in google for an answer and couldn't get it. I am searching for a `angular firebase passwordless login`, but instead of a person clicking `login` and writing his `email` I want that I could write persons `email` and he could `login` via `link` in his own network/pc.

This tutorial shows how to implement passwordless login if a person doing it by himself (creates email on local-storage) - so I can't create account for another person :

[Angular Firebase Passwordless login](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/using-passwordless-signup-with-firebase-on-the-web/)

**Can I make passwordless account for another person, writing just his email ? And if it's so - could anyone link or try to explain ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can theoretically do that (email invite feature). However, the user being sent the link will need to confirm their email before completing sign-in to prevent session fixation attacks (stored email will not be available as link is opened in a different device). It is similar to a user starting sign in with email link and opening the link on a different device.